# Protons and electrons near each other

Tags: electrons, protons

For context: I am an electrical engineer planning to do a masters in photonics. So I've been studying electromagnetics and trying to understand it with a little more depth than what undergrad engineering electromagnetics classes taught me. Disclaimer: I am not even close to being an intermediate sort of electromagnetism-guy

Question: On doing some standard google searches, I have found 2 "events" that can happen between a single electron and a single proton. One is that they "combine" to form a simple hydrogen atom. The other is a relatively more complex "reaction" where they combine to form a neutron and a neutrino which I believe is called the "electron capture". So here is my two-part question-

1) If we have a hypothetical free electron and free proton close to each other but nowhere near other stuff, what is likely to happen? Combination of the two to form a Hydrogen atom or the reaction where a neutrino is produced? Or is there a third option I missed?

2) Is there a straightforward reason why they just don't come close enough to "stick" to each other? If so, what is it? If not, what is the reason? And considering I am not familiar with particle physics by a long shot, what do I need to do in order to understand these phenomena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A single proton and a single electron cannot undergo electron capture because the combined mass of the two particles is less than the mass of a neutron. A neutron is about 1.29 MeV heavier than a proton, and an electron is only 0.511 MeV in mass. It is possible for a relativistic-speed collision between a proton and electron to produce a neutron and neutrino using the added kinetic energy to form the required mass via $E=mc^2$. So, the only interaction between a free electron and free proton is to form a hydrogen atom.
2. In one sense, a hydrogen atom is a proton stuck to an electron. In another sense, particles cannot stick to each other because they do not have solid surfaces. They can only be bound to each other via various forces (electromagnetic forces in this case) and confined to a limited volume. Within this volume, the position of a fundamental particle is fundamentally uncertain. An electron's existence is spread out over space and can overlap with the proton, which is how electron capture happens in larger atoms.

Comment: What do you mean by "confined to a limited volume"? Is this volume fixed quantitatively?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya When you calculate where an electron can be when it is bonded to a proton, you get [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital). The diagrams in the article show where the electron will be found 99.99...% of the times you look. Technically, the probability of finding an electron at any location in the universe is not zero, but with extremely high probability it will be found at a small distance from the nucleus. For a lowest-energy electron, the most probable distance is [50 pm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius).

Answer (score 0):

[Electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture) does not occur for a single proton. It takes certain proton rich nuclei to achieve this. Depending on the initial conditions a proton and an electron can scatter or combine to ultimately form a hydrogen atom.

Your second question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that an electron and a proton cannot:"stick" to each other is that they both obey quantum mechanics, specifically the Heisenberg  uncertainty principal. A proton has a charge radius that is less than a fm.  An electron confined in a region that small would have an enormous momentum uncertainty, an hence could not remain in that location. To understand these phenomena you need to learn quantum mechanics.

Comment: I have always had trouble understanding why uncertainty in momentum is sometimes compared to momentum itself. Although they have the same units, aren't the two quantities fundamentally different? But either way, thanks for your answer